# Trying to move data stored in JSON strings in database into a more manageable structure/process. Are NOSQL approaches potentially a good fit here?

Tags: json, nosql, persistence, relational-database, ravendb

Folks,
I have been tasked with recforing a large system that comprises many javascript based worktools/workflows into something more manageable.

The first part of this is to refactor the data. All data is currently stored as JSON strings in a SQL database. So for each worktool which could be anything from a set of forms to an interactive chart all data is stored as one JSON string in a record associated with the worktool.

Now I have been told that due to the complexity of the object graph behind some of these worktools that it would be fairly futile to look for commonalities that would allow me to model a relational schema from the data. That this schema would either have to be some really generic key value based structure, or that we would need hundreds of tables.

Im wondering now if there is value in using a non relational persistance mechanism, such as NOSQL. I am only looking into this now, but I would really appreciate anyones opinions here who have experience of a similar context of operation or of NOSQL products and process.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move your data as is to RavenDB.
It natively understand JSON and you can start querying / working with those documents as first class members.
RavenDB also has a great set of client libraries, which make working with it a breeze.

Comment: Thats great Ayende. I know my outline of the problem space is a little vague, but would you consider this a good fit technology wise?